# Why decider D behaves the opposite when it is using decider H as a subroutine?

Tags: turing-machines, decidable

[image]

Acoordind to paragraph shown, how decider D uses H as a subroutine and how it is behaving the opposite ?

It would be very useful if someone clarify this ?

Comment: _In an abstract way._ Because TM is an abstract concept. It's not that it is a strictly defined programming language or something. This statement only says that D can do the same as H, and that it reverts the output. The actual notion of that depends on your preffered notion of TM, and what H does.

Comment: so, output can even be same ?

Comment: No, of course not, it's opposite _by definition_.

Comment: This is actually the thing which confuses me . Can you please elaborate, if possible ?

Comment: Careful! Rejecting does not only mean stopping in non-accepting state but also running forever. For these non-ending computations the machine D should accept because H rejects. However, the subroutine H will not stop, thus D will not stop and be considered to reject. Thus the machine D cannot actually exist/work. This would work only for recursive languages, not for all recursively enumerable ones.

Answer (score 1):

Turing machine is said to *accept* the input, if it ends in the accepting state(s) given that input. It *rejects*, if it ends in any other state.

So, if we have a machine `H` that takes input `<M, <M>>`, we then can enhance it, by adding new starting point, taking as input `<M>`, constructing `<M, <M>>` and then feeding this to the rest of the `H`. This new machine `H*` will be same as `H`, but with different input. If we now switch accepting and rejecting states we will have machine, that takes as input `<M>` and returns result opposite to `H`, which coinsidentally is `D`.